# Can I save my Linq Iqueriable to the DB using MVC 4 and EF 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, linq-to-sql

I would like to do a query on Truck table and then save the results in the Vehicles table. Is this possible and if so can you show me an example. I've been stuck on this problem for a while.

```
 IQueryable<TruckModel> result =
        from d in db.Truck
        select new TruckModel()
        {
            Model = d.Model
            Color = d.Color;
        };


            var record = new Vehicles();
            record.Model = model.Model;
            record.Color = model.Color;
            db.Points.Add(record);
            db.SaveChanges();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
```

Comment: You should probably.. I don't know.. *use* your `result` variable?

Answer (score 1):

The pitfall is here

```
record.Model = model.Model;
record.Color = model.Color;
```

I guess what you intent is

```
 record.Model = result.Model;
```